# When I click on "heroku create" it keeps showing another project

Tags: node.js, heroku

[image]

When I run `heroku create` it should have "Burger-2" in the blue and green Heroku links, but it does not.

I am logged into my Heroku account, so why is it doing that?

Comment: [Please don't post text in screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That's how it works](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps#creating-an-app-without-a-name) if you don't provide request a specific name:

> If no app name is specified, a random name will be generated.

If you want to use a name of your choice, [pass it in](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps#creating-a-named-app):

```
heroku create Burger-2
```

If `Burger-2` is available, Heroku will create an app with that name for you. It might not be available, though:

> Since Heroku app names are in a global namespace, you can expect that common names, like “blog” or “wiki”, will already be taken. It’s often easier to start with a default name and [rename the app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps) later.